# Divide a constant with a pdf

Tags: probability

I want to find the probability function for the time it takes before a stock with S items becomes zero. I know the pdf of the variable D (demand per week). I want to find the pdf in weeks for the time it takes before the stock is zero. The variable D has a gamma distribution with know parameters k and Theta. So the problem is to find the pdf for variable T:   T = S/D. I would appreciate assistance with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Going back to the basic principles: the probability that $a<\frac{S}{D}<a+h$  is the probability that $\frac{S}{a+h}<D<\frac{S}{a}$. The latter is approximately the probability density of $D$ at $S/a$ (denoted $\varphi_D(S/a)$) multiplied by the length of $[\frac{S}{a+h},\frac{S}{a}]$. Thus, letting $h\to 0$ we get the probability density of $S/D$ as the limit 
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{1}{h} \varphi_D(S/a)\left(\frac{S}{a}-\frac{S}{a+h}\right) = \frac{S}{a^2}\varphi_D(S/a) $$
Recognizing that the limit above is (up to a sign) the derivative of $S/a$ with respect to $a$, you should be able to generalize the formula.